# ASP.NET core 2.1 API hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having an issue with my deployment on IIS, in the sense when I start the API from VS 2017 and try the API on Postman it's working fine, but when I deploys it on IIS nothing is happening, could anyone insight me on the proper way to deploy APS.NET CORE 2.1 on IIS.

Thank you

Comment: Please share more details about the error you are facing? Have you followed the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I managed to find the root cause which is 500 internal error and was occurring because IIS_IUSR was not having permission, but there's another issue arose now in the sense when I perform POST operation from Postman it indicates it's done but when I check Database there's nothing! any hints would be appreciated @MohsinMehmood

Comment: Ok @MohsinMehmood I managed to figured it out it was from the Pool Identity

Answer (score 0):

Might want to give this a read: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS